# Make selected Jquery FAQ bold when clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple Jquery FAQ please see following Fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/qkwhLmkk/4/

I am trying to get the selected question to highlight (go bold) when selected and in the open state. I have tried to apply the '.active' and '.visited' states to the relevant 'dt' element with no success:

```
.faqs dt:active          {font-weight:bold;}
.faqs dt:visited         {font-weight:bold;}
```

I think I may need to modify the relevant jscript with some kind of reference to ':click' but not sure how?

Comment: checkout this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w5vf7oak/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is a bit messy but i see you have a `click()` function in your JQ code. why not use that to toggleClass `clicked` on the clicked faq ? see snippet below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // ---- FAQs ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  $('.faqs dd').hide(); // Hide all DDs inside .faqs
  $('.faqs dt').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover')
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover')
  }).click(function() { // Add class "hover" on dt when hover
    $(this).toggleClass("clicked")
  $(this).next().slideToggle('normal'); // Toggle dd when the respective dt is clicked
  });

});
```

```css
/* FAQ */

dl,
dt,
dd {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 643px
}

.faqs dt {
  padding: 2px 0 2px 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: underline
}

.faqs dt:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.faqs dt:active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.faqs dt:visited {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.faqs dd {
  padding: 0 0 5px 30px;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 1.5em
}
.clicked {
 font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="faqs">
  <dt>How to do I get this bold on 'click'?</dt>
  <dd>
    Selected question should now be bold
  </dd>

  <dt>How to do I get this bold on 'click'?</dt>
  <dd>
    Selected question should now be bold
  </dd>

  <dt>How to do I get this bold on 'click'?</dt>
  <dd>
    Selected question should now be bold
  </dd>

  <dt>How to do I get this bold on 'click'?</dt>
  <dd>
    Selected question should now be bold
  </dd>




</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a class:

```
.active {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

And your jQuery should look like this:

```
$('dt').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

see fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vske2nt1/1/

Comment: not actually a good solution because , in your example , i open 1 it gets bold, i open a second , the first one gets ' unbolded ' but it's still open . then if i click to close it ( the first one that i opened which is now not bolded ) , it closes but gets bolded . that's not a good behavior . If you want to make your solution viable you should also close previous opened faq when click on another faq so that you have only one faq opened at one time

Comment: oh sorry, completely missed the fact that the idea was to keep all the clicked ones bolded. Glad you found an answer though, sorry couldn't help you myself

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.faqs dt').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings("dt").css("fontWeight", "normal");
    $(this).css("fontWeight", "bold");
});
```

Use this code to make it bold purpose only Rest all logic will remain as up to you.